# MYSQL: Identify the five actors who share the greatest number of films with Nick Wahlberg (Sakila Database)

Tags: mysql, sql

table 1: film_actor
contains:

```
film_id,
actor_id
```

table 2: actor
contains

```
actor_id,
first_name,
last_name
```

I have tried:

```
  select actor.id, actor.first_name, actor.last_name, count(*)
from actor
join film_actor am on actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
where film_id in (select film_id from film_actor where actor_id = 'Nick Wahlberg')
group by actor.actor_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

I realize I am probably very off.

Comment: Hello Yung Noor, welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking a SQL question, you should show your current attempt at solving the problem. It is also a good practice to provide sample data and expected results, as tabular text.

Comment: SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name, COUNT(*) AS "Films wih Nick" 
 FROM film_actor JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
 WHERE actor.last_name = "Wahlberg" I realize I'm probably very off though.

Comment: OK. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60516764/edit) to add your query in the question itself, where it will be easier to see.

Comment: Can you tell us what results you are getting from the query you added, and whether/how they differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking it down, you'd want to start with all the movies that nick starred in:

```sql
select film_id, actor_id
  from film_actor
  inner join actor using (actor_id)
  where first_name = 'nick'
```

*The `actor_id` field will become important later*

Subsequently, you'd want to find the actors that starred in that list of movies, but aren't nick. For that you can join against an uncorrelated subquery:

```sql
select actor.actor_id, first_name
from actor
inner join film_actor using (actor_id)
inner join (
  select film_id, actor_id nick_actor_id
  from film_actor
  inner join actor using (actor_id)
  where first_name = 'nick'
) co_starring on film_actor.film_id = co_starring.film_id and actor.actor_id <> co_starring.nick_actor_id
```

Finally, you perform the grouping and ordering:

```sql
select actor.actor_id, first_name, count(*) as co_starred
from actor
inner join film_actor using (actor_id)
inner join (
  select film_id, actor_id nick_actor_id
  from film_actor
  inner join actor using (actor_id)
  where first_name = 'nick'
) co_starring on film_actor.film_id = co_starring.film_id and actor.actor_id <> co_starring.nick_actor_id
group by actor_id, first_name
order by co_starred desc;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f1854/8)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
    SELECT actor.first_name, actor.last_name, COUNT(*) AS "Films wih Nick" 
    FROM film_actor JOIN actor ON film_actor.actor_id = actor.actor_id
    WHERE 
    exists(select 1 from actor b 
where b.film_id = film_actor.film_id and b.last_name = "Wahlberg")
    and film_actor.last_name <> "Wahlberg"
    order by 3 desc
    limit 5
```